# Translate on the local axis

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to make a plane to translate on the local Z axis of an Empty object. Can someone suggest on what i should be doing in hightlighted portion of the node network in Geometry Nodes.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move a grid along the local *Z-axis* of another object, apply the following node tree:

[image]

Here I rotate the desired direction vector with the *Rotation* of the other object and add this value to the *Location*.

You can change the distance by changing the direction vector.

---

As an alternative you can also use the following setup:

[image]

Here I first convert the object to be moved into an instance. This has the advantage that I can then use the node `Translate Instances` to move this object along its local axes.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you should multiply it by vector (0,0,1):

[image]

Comment: Actually, if my understanding is correct, your solution may be useful on translating based on the local Z axis of the geometry node object with Empty acting as just an offset controller. Sorry, i was looking for something different.